# MySQL - Get last record for each membership based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I need some help for a query:

```
Table Customers
id        name       email
1         john       john@abc.com
2         doe        doe@abc.com

Table Membership
id      facility       package
1       a              x
2       b              y
3       c              z

Table Orders
id      orderid        result            customerid      membershipid
1       order-1        Unsuccessful      1               1
2       order-2        Successful        2               1
3       order-3        Successful        1               1
4       order-4        Successful        1               2
5       order-5        Unsuccessful      1               2
```

What i want to achieve is get last order which were unsuccessful against a customer for each membership

which means that query should return only order-5 in this case. as last record of membershipid 1 is successful.

Till now, i have used this query but it returns max of unsuccessful record and does not obey last record.

I hope i have explained my issue.

Here is the query

```
SELECT o.transactionresult FROM orders o where o.transactionresult='Unsuccessful' group by o.membershipid ORDER by o.id DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by last you mean the last by id then you can use NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT o.* 
FROM orders o 
where o.transactionresult='Unsuccessful'
and not exists (
  select 1 from orders
  where membershipid = o.membershipid and id > o.id
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tp1aTK4DUefLkjjBXhFdgd/0).

In case you want membership per customer:

```
SELECT o.* 
FROM orders o 
where o.transactionresult='Unsuccessful'
and not exists (
  select 1 from orders
  where membershipid = o.membershipid and customerid = o.customerid and id > o.id
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tp1aTK4DUefLkjjBXhFdgd/1).
Results:

```
| id  | orderid | transactionresult | customerid | membershipid |
| --- | ------- | ----------------- | ---------- | ------------ |
| 5   | order-5 | Unsuccessful      | 1          | 2            |
```

Comment: what about records against specific customer, will the condition be put in main query or subquery or both?

Comment: i meant if i have to get customer 1 record, then i will put the condition in main query. right?

Comment: Yes: `where o.customerid = 1 and o.transactionresult='Unsuccessful'
and not exists...`

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation for this:

```
select o.customer, o.membership, max(o.id)
from orders o
group by o.customer, o.membership
having max(o.id) = max(case when o.result = 'Unsuccessful' then o.id end);
```

This returns customer/membership combination where the maximum id is the maximum id that is unsuccessful.

If you want the full row, I would use a correlated subquery:

```
select o.*
from orders o
where o.result = 'Unsuccessful' and
      o.id = (select max(o2.id)
              from orders o2
              where o2.customer = o.customer and o2.membership = o.membership
             );
```

This checks that the result is unsuccessful and that the id is the biggest id for the customer/membership combination.